# Hide button after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide the button after it has been clicked. Once the button is  clicked, there is no use for it so I would like to hide it , but keep the confirmation message

Here's the existing code that does everything properly (except hide the button after the click):

```
  <a class="btn btn-danger _btn_" onclick="save()">Register button</a>
  <div id="confirmation"></div>





  function save() {
    var number_i = $('#number_i').text();
    var date_s = $('#date_s').text();
    var name_p = "<?php echo $_POST['product_name']; ?>";


    if (number_i != '___') {
      $.post('saveEntry.php', {number: number_i, date: date_s, name: name_p}, function() {
        $('#confirmation').text('Info: the data was saved!');
        $('#confirmation').attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
      })
    } else {
      alert('Introdu Numar Bon Fiscal!');
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$('._btn_').hide();
```

or perhaps adding an id to it:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger _btn_" id="button-to-hide" onclick="save()">Register button</a>
...

$('#button-to-hide').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code just inside your click event.

```
$(this).css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to you save function

```
$(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

---

```
    <a class="btn btn-danger _btn_" onclick="save()">Register button</a>
  <div id="confirmation"></div>


 function save() {
    $('.btn-danger').hide()
    var number_i = $('#number_i').text();
    var date_s = $('#date_s').text();
    var name_p = "<?php echo $_POST['product_name']; ?>";


    if (number_i != '___') {
      $.post('saveEntry.php', {number: number_i, date: date_s, name: name_p}, function() {
        $('#confirmation').text('Info: the data was saved!');
        $('#confirmation').attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
      })
    } else {
      alert('Introdu Numar Bon Fiscal!');
    }
  };
```

---

---